# How to create a method that replace semicolons for line breaks?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to create a method that receives a string, replaces the semicolons (";") with line breaks, and then returns it.

I tried it with that's code:

```
methods: {
    programasMethod(programas){
       if(programas){
        return programas.replaceAll(";", "\n");
       }  
    }
}
```

I tried using the method *programasMethod(programas)* inside a template but it returns the string without the semicolons (";") and without the lines breaks.

```html
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <template v-for="item of actividades">
        <ul>
            <li>{{ programasMethod(item.programa) }}</li>
        <ul>
    </template>
</div>
```

[image: That image show the result on the web]

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <template v-for="item of actividades">
         <ul v-if="item.programa">
            <li v-for="(elem, i) in item.programa.split(';')" :key="i">{{ elem }} <br /></li>
        </ul>
    </template>
</div>
```

**[EDIT]**

You can also do this:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <template v-for="item of actividades">
        <ul>
            <li v-html="programasMethod(item.programa)"></li>
        <ul>
    </template>
</div>
```

and

```
methods: {
    programasMethod(programas){
       if(programas){
        return programas.replaceAll(";", "<br />");
       }  
    }
}
```

Comment: without any additional function

Comment: I tried it but appear that error: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Comment: Make sure that all elements of **`item`** have a programa key!

Comment: If you're using **Node 14.xx or +**, you can use **optional chaining** like this

item.programa?.split(';')

Comment: @LuisFelipeMorenoRondón let me know if it's work!